# Convert two integers into timestamp

Tags: db2, timestamp, type-conversion, db2-midrange

How do I convert two integers, one for date and one for time, into a timestamp?

- Given 20200304 and 1046, return a timestamp for April 3, 2020, 10:46 AM.
- Given 20200304 and 946, return a timestamp for April 3, 2020, 9:46 AM.
- Given 20200304 and 2359, return a timestamp for April 3, 2020, 11:59 PM.
- Given 20200304 and 0, return a timestamp for April 3, 2020, 0:00 AM.

I'm running Version 7, Revision 1.

Comment: Which version of DB2 for iSeries are you on?

Comment: @mustaccio V7R1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH T (YYYYMMDD, HHMM) AS 
(
VALUES
  (20200304, 1046) -- return a timestamp for April 3, 2020, 10:46 AM.
, (20200304,  946) -- return a timestamp for April 3, 2020, 9:46 AM.
, (20200304, 2359) -- return a timestamp for April 3, 2020, 11:59 PM.
, (20200304,    0) -- return a timestamp for April 3, 2020, 0:00 AM.
)
SELECT 
  YYYYMMDD, HHMM
, TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(DIGITS(DEC(YYYYMMDD, 8)) || DIGITS(DEC(HHMM, 4)), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MI') AS TS 
FROM T;
```

The result is:

```
|YYYYMMDD   |HHMM       |TS                 |
|-----------|-----------|-------------------|
|20200304   |1046       |2020-03-04 10:46:00|
|20200304   |946        |2020-03-04 09:46:00|
|20200304   |2359       |2020-03-04 23:59:00|
|20200304   |0          |2020-03-04 00:00:00|
```

Comment: Much better than my horrible brute-force hack. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a brute force solution, but I'm still hoping there's a better way:

```
TIMESTAMP(
    FLOOR(MYDATE / 10000)
    CONCAT '-'
    CONCAT MOD(FLOOR(MYDATE / 100),100)
    CONCAT '-'
    CONCAT MOD(MYDATE, 100)
    CONCAT ' '
    CONCAT CASE
        WHEN MYTIME < 100 THEN '00:' CONCAT MYTIME
        ELSE FLOOR(MYTIME/100) CONCAT ':' CONCAT MOD(MYTIME,100)
    END
    CONCAT ':00'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative might be

```
timestamp_format(
  substr(digits(mydate),3) || 
  substr(digits(mytime), 7), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MI');
```

Comment: For me this query just returns '++++++++++++++' for all the timestamps. The one from Mark Barinstein worked, though.